# Add variable before each attribute in string

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

I am walking through some attributes in a shortcode in wordpress with code. I got all attributes in one string. Like this:

```
$var = 'type="text" title="super title" class="master-module"';
```

I want to convert it to:

```
$var = 'data-type="text" data-title="super title" data-class="master-module"';
```

I have tried to understand using preg replace but I terrible at regex.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It can be done without regex. `strstr()` and `str_replace()` is what you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a regex like this:

```
(\w+=")
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/xL0wY6/2)**

And this replace string:

```
data-$1
```

You can see the match and capturing groups in green and in the substitution section your resulting string after applying the replacement string.

[image]

The php code:

```
$re = "/(\\w+=\")/"; 
$str = "\$var = 'type=\"text\" title=\"super title\" class=\"master-module\"';\n\n"; 
$subst = "data-\1"; 

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

**Update:** If you have an attribute with dashes like `heading-type="xxx xx"` then you can use this regex instead:

```
([\w-]+=")
```

Comment: Hi! I love your preg_replace function. When I tried it and bug tested it. If the attribute is heading-type="xxx xx" instead of just one word. It don't return what I want

Answer (score 0):

You can explode, apply the wanted addition on every element that needs to be prefixed, and implode your string to get the expected result :

```
$var = 'type="text" title="super title" class="master-module"';

$var = explode (' ', $var);
array_walk ($var, function (&$a) {
  if (strpos($a, '"') !== strlen($a) - 1)
    $a = 'data-' . $a;
});
$var = implode (' ', $var);
// data-type="text" data-title="super title" data-class="master-module"
```

That way, you could also add an array to your array_walk call to include a list of values to modify or to exclude also.

Comment: As you have added the output to your code, you can see that the contents of the title have been changed as well.

Comment: If the attribute value has a space in it, the explode function won't work.

Comment: @FredrikNordström Ups, my bad, I changed it so it works even with spaces. Just in case you don't want to use a regex

Answer (score 0):

Here is my final code and answer.

```
$re = '/([\w-]+=")/'; 
$str = $moduleAttribute; 
$subst = 'data-$1'; 

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

I just have one word. Thanks!
Especially thank you @fede